# UITableView with floating cells

Tags: ios, layout, uitableview, position

I am working on a specific type of list for an iOS app, where cells would simply have a specific width and height and then float left (think of something like CSS `float:left`), creating then a list that would scroll if more than 12 items (like the picture bellow).

[image]

I was thinking that perhaps this could be done by customizing UITableViewCell and setting the frame's width and height, so I could re-use the various benefits UITableViewController, delegate and dataSource offer. but unfortunately it seems that's not possible.
So, I'm now simply creating many UIViews and positioning them across its parent programatically.

I just would like to make sure this would be the right approach to achieve such kind of lists and if someone could let me know if it's indeed not possible to have this kind of functionality on UITableView and inherit all the goodness it offers.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this question is already answered, but still...

I believe you can simply use UICollectionView since iOS 6.0.

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)

And this is how it looks like ([image](http://www.howzhi.com/files/course/2013/02/01/1015451b622c889967.jpeg))

Maybe this will help somebody.

Comment: Thanks, I guess for the sake of keeping things updated here we should mark your answer as correct for the features iOS provides nowadays. cheers

Answer (score 1):

UITableView can only have cells that go in one direction. It's perfectly okay to create many UIViews (table view cells are also UIViews), if the number of them is reasonable. You can usually have a few hundred UIViews in a scrollview without seeing any performance issues, but that also depends on the complexity of what's inside the uiviews. Try it for yourself and if you find out, that you need too many uiviews, or that their complexity it too high, you can optimize further. You can set the `.layer.shouldRasterize` property to "cache" the content of the views. Or you can use CATiledLayer, which is something like a UITableView, but it supports *tiles* in all direction (and scrolling, zooming, ...).

Comment: thank you for the answer John, good to know it's not a bad approach. I will definitely have a look at these methods in case the app gets too complex.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this project, I think may be helpful to for your problem

[link](https://github.com/provideal/MMGridView)